# HTML Submit button does not work on android, does work on laptop

Tags: html, forms, submit

I have a form in my HTML file, when I use it on my computer it does submit, but when I try to use it on my phone it doesn't. Does anyone know why, and how to fix it? I also tried it with a JS, but that didn't help either.

```
<form id="contact_form" action="mailto:example@somewhere.com" method="post">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your name.."><br>

      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email.."><br>

      <label for="phone">Phone</label>
      <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Your phone number.."><br>

      <label for="subject">Subject</label>
      <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="The subject of the message.."><br>

      <label for="subject">Question</label>
      <textarea id="question" name="question" placeholder="Write your question here.."></textarea><br>

      <!-- <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="checkAndSubmit('contact_form')"> -->
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      <input type="reset" value="Reset">
    </form>
```

```
function checkAndSubmit(formID) {
  a=prompt("Input");
  if(a=="ok"){
    document.getElementById(formID).submit();
  }
}
```

I have tried multiple things that were suggested on Stack Overflow and some other sites, but they didn't solve it either.

**EDIT:** Just tested it on Safari on an iPhone 11, where it works, the phone that it doesn't work on is an Android 6.0 with Chrome

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get mailto working on android chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53763882/how-to-get-mailto-working-on-android-chrome)

Comment: What happens if you try method="get"? The mailto scheme is designed for use with GET (such as in a link).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa767737(v=vs.85)

Comment: @fraggley sadly serverside isn't an option and the hidden anchor tag is not that nice to use.
I also have another mailto tag `contact me at <a href="mailto:r0782221@student.thomasmore.be">somthing@mail.com</a>` at the bottom that works, but that one is not related to the form.

Comment: @PeterWaher I just tried it, but no luck